# AngularJS - Injecting CSS on each page

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Before I start, I want to emphasize that I am new at both javascript and Angular.js

I am currently using tennisgent's [angular-routing-styles](https://github.com/tennisgent/angular-route-styles) and it works sometimes. 
I did everything correctly but for some reason occasionally there's a delay that causes CSS to not load when switching through the navigation, showing unformatted html for a split second.

[AngularCSS](https://github.com/door3/angular-css) by door3 simply doesn't work for me, I tried installing it three times and it just causes everything to fail.

I can't put all of this in a jsfiddle, so I've included a temporary tunnel to my local webserver: http://e5fe67b0.ngrok.io

Switch between music and about a few times and you'll see the lag happening occasionally.

Why is this happening?

Comment: why do you need stylesheets per route? is your CSS too big, even after minifying? Maybe it would be better if you include one concated+minified CSS file for you whole app!  Does it work if you use just 1 css file?

Comment: As you can see by switching, the nav bar highlights what is selected + there are elements on each page that need to be dynamic to the individual page.

Comment: yes, but you don't need to achieve that with CSS files per routes! Maybe just add a class to body on specific routes.

Comment: the problem here is that the CSS loads after switching the route, when you already have the CSS loaded there will be no "flash of unstyled content " (FOUC)

Comment: I would but there's a unspoken rule about inline css http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm

Comment: angular-routing-styles was supposed to cause the css to load before injecting the html, which is my issue here.

Comment: who says something about inline css ;)  for example you can use ``angular.element('body').addClass('page')``

Comment: "unspoken rules" are the cause of useless arguments, like tables vs. divs.  Do what works for you.  If inline CSS is satisfactory, use it.

Comment: I added an answer, thank you Brent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So using a `<style>css here</style>`
in each page solved it for me.

It seems that those scripts are outdated and no longer works correctly with angular.js so using inline or `<style>` should work fine.